# Parallel Handling Kafka messages in a Windows Service using C#

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka

I have Windows service written in C#. Earlier we were using Event hubs with multiple partitions for message queuing. We recently moved to Kafka. For implementing Event hubs in c# , we have `IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync` , which keeps listening to event hub notifications and is triggered whenever a message is posted to event hub , which runs asynchronously in the background

I did not find any equivalent method in Kafka.

My requirement here is to subscribe to a Kafka topic and continuously consume messages. When a message is consumed, some other operations are also supposed to executed for that message. For each message say the execution time takes around 15 mins, I want the Kafka consumer to consume all messages and keep it in queue as when it receives and writes it into a file. Other process should read the file, pick the message and do other operations. I want all of them to run simultaneously/parallelly.

PS : I have written a console application which can produce and consume one message.What I'm looking for is queuing and parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

For paralellism Kafka implements what's known as [consumer groups](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-consumers/index.html). Kafka stores the "offsets" (read: key of record across a topic) and also stores the offsets of where a given consumer group is also at in processing the records. This should allow you to create new consumer instances on the fly using the same program, and by changing the group allow two programs to consume the same data in paralell for different tasks.

I found this link helpful when I was creating my first consumer as well, in case you found a way to create it without a groupId: http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-consumer/index.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have look at Silverback: https://silverback-messaging.net. It abstracts many of those concerns and the basic usage is as simple as this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddSilverback()
            .WithConnectionToMessageBroker(options => options.AddKafka())
            .AddKafkaEndpoints(
                endpoints => endpoints
                    .Configure(
                        config =>
                        {
                            config.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
                        })
                .AddInbound(
                    endpoint => endpoint
                        .ConsumeFrom("my-topic")
                        .DeserializeJson(serializer => serializer.UseFixedType<SomeMessage>())
                        .Configure(
                            config =>
                            {
                                config.GroupId = "test-consumer-group";
                                config.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            })))

            .AddSingletonSubscriber<MySubscriber>();
    }
}

public class MySubscriber
{
    public Task OnMessageReceived(SomeMessage message)
    {
        // TODO: process message
    }
}
```